# Print Manager Does not Show Printers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, print-server

Server 2012 R2 have about 40 printers installed all TCP/IP port based printers shared out.

I was able to see and manage the printers on the print server via print manager, and then all of a sudden I can no longer see printers in the print manager view.

ports, forms, drivers etc I see fine and as I understand it the printers are more of a push back to the print manager client.

DNS A Record is present for the server name.

I can access the special printers share view by using the hostname on the server via UNC, then choosing view remote printers.

I can manage via Print Manager from any other client I have in same subnet as well as out of it.

I cant manage another print servers printers from this server either, same behavior for the local server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the MS forums and ended up finding that this patch was the culprit, once uninstalled and rebooted the Print Manager UI started rendering installed printers once again.

(KB2995388)

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2995388?wa=wsignin1.0

not sure what "fix" in the list actually killed it.

Comment: Please do accept this answer when you get a chance.  Hopefully that will reduce the number of folks trying to respond to this question with not-an-answers and really bad answers.

Answer (score -1):

I had this situation until I installed KB2978719 
It may have just been the restart the fixed it but I thought I would share my experience.

Answer (score -1):

On my two Print servers I resolved this issue by installing the Microsoft November 2014 update [KB3000850](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3000850).